# Recording is not playing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, qt5, audio-recording, irrklang

I am implementing this in my app

```
mAudioPlayer = mSoundEngine->play2D(localMainFilePath.toStdString().c_str(), false, false, true);
```

mAudioPlayer is of type

```
irrklang::ISound *mAudioPlayer;
```

When i try to play recording crash occured saying access voilation on debugging I am getting
    mAudioPlayer has 0x00000000

why mAudioPlayer is not intialising.

Comment: Are you properly creating the mAudioPlayer object?

Comment: yes Its playing mp3 songs but not mp3 recording and this issue is on window xp but on window 7 It is working perfect

Comment: So the issue is happening just with a specific file?

Comment: I got that my program is not making mp3 file in app temp folder in window xp